# Filter with multiple values in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I want to filter worksheet excluding all values stored in another worksheet in column A. For that store all the values into an array

```
xArray = Worksheets("MainRef").Range("A1:A" & Worksheets("MainRef").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value2
```

And trying to filter with following command

```
rngTar.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=xArray, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

but its not work. Kindly guide me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is your array `xArray`.

```
xArray = Worksheets("MainRef").Range("A1:A" & Worksheets("MainRef").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value2
```

When you store values in array using above line it creates a `2-dimensional array`. The first dimension is the rows and second dimension is the columns. When you'll see the Type of your array in `Local window` it displays `Variant(1 to 5, 1 to 1)` where 5 is number of rows(mentioned 5 just for example) and 1 is number of columns.

So when you use xArray to filter the range it will not work as a 2 dimensional array is created even you have selected only one column.

Instead you can use following approach to load values in array:

```
Dim N As Long
With Sheets("MainRef")
    N = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim xArray(1 To N)
    For i = 1 To N
        xArray(i) = .Cells(i, 1)
    Next i
End With
```